# How to return a reference to the reference passed in function argument?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, copy, arguments

Ok, so what I'm trying to do is pass a reference to a function, then return that same reference without copying. I don't want to use move because that can "empty" the contents of the original variable. This is what I want in pseudo code

```
a;    
b = func(a);    
change(b); // a changes as well
```

I understand you can do this with pointers (   auto * b = &a),
but I want to see if it can be done with a function. This is what I tried:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<class T>
T& returnRef1(T* t){
    return *t;
}
template<class T>
T& returnRef2(T& t){
    return t;
}

int main(){
    vector<int> vec1 = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    auto * p2v = &vec1;
    vector<int>  vec2 = returnRef1(p2v);
    vector<int> vec3 = returnRef2(vec1);
    vec2[0] = 1000;
    vec3[1] = 999;
    cout << "vec1[0]=" << vec1[0] << " vec1[1]=" << vec1[1] << endl;
    cout << "vec2[0]=" << vec2[0] << " vec2[1]=" << vec2[1] << endl;
    cout << "vec3[0]=" << vec3[0] << " vec3[1]=" << vec3[1] << endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

what prints

```
vec1[0]=0 vec1[1]=1
vec2[0]=1000 vec2[1]=1
vec3[0]=0 vec3[1]=999
```

what i want

```
vec1[0]=1000 vec1[1]=999
vec2[0]=1000 vec2[1]=999
vec3[0]=1000 vec3[1]=999
```

I understand that my vector is getting copied at some point(either in arguments and/or return) and I don't want that.

Comment: `change(b); // a changes as well` This is probably not a good idea.

Comment: _@Michael_ How does this comprise a ***minimal*** sample?? Remove all the irrelevant code please!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `vector<int> &vec3 = returnRef2(vec1);` instead of `vector<int> vec3 = returnRef2(vec1);`.

Comment: Thanks! (min char limit)